# Broken packages when trying to install Wine

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, dependencies

Im trying to get wine but every time i do it gives me this error

```
sudo apt-get install winehq-staging
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-staging : Depends: wine-staging (= 6.17~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Im on Kubuntu 20.04!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: You've not provided your OS & release details; but your paste includes non-Ubuntu (ie. 3rd party) packages so details are useful in understanding your issue, how you got there, and thus the correct fix.

Comment: im on Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: Just checked, and `wine-staging` is not in the repositories, so where does it come from?

Comment: I'm assuming you have added a ppa. Unless you have a specific need for an advanced version of wine, remove all that stuff and use the version in the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: You probably misspellt the package name. The correct name [from WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) is `winehq-staging`  .

Comment: I edited it, i still get the same error except this time its just 1. But i cannot find any solution still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is actually caused by the wine ppa not having a the new version of libvkd3d.
The answer is just to wait a while, they will eventually fix it. you can use winehq-stable meanwhile.

edit:
seems like they are aware of the issue https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=35655
edit 2: They seem to be updating the ppa right now!

edit 3:
run apt clean and apt update and try again, it works!

Comment: you can also check this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/pma2pb/wine_617_cannot_be_installed_due_to_missing/

Comment: Thanks mate i realized yesterday it got fixed, thanks for your help guys, now how do i close this so people stop responding?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [wine repository](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main' 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Comment: same error, nothing is fixed